# jQuery Slider - Pular entre valores definidos e sync com outros 2 sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Tenho a seguinte necessidade. Tenho que fazer uma solução similar à Locaweb onde movo 3 sliders ao mesmo tempo. E eles devem ter os steps definidos de acordo com os valores do plano.

Exemplo: https://www.locaweb.com.br/cloud/cloud-hosting/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Primeira dúvida é: Como estabelecer os steps dinamicamente entre os valores? Eu tenho um array (2, 4, 8, 16, 32) que são os valores da "memória" por exemplo. Mas não consigo fazer com que o slider pule para a próxima opção.

A outra dúvida é: Como fazer com que os slides sejam acionados ao mesmo tempo?

```
$(function(){

    var arrayCPU = [2,4,8,16,32];
    var arrayRAM = [7,15,30,60,120];
    var arrayDisco = [50,100,200,400,400];

    $("#sliderCPU").slider({
        min: 2,
        max: 120
    });
    $("#sliderRAM").slider({
        min: 7,
        max: 120
    });
    $("#sliderDisco").slider({
        min: 50,
        max: 50
    });

});
```

Comment: Ainda não consegui nenhum retorno a respeito :/

Comment: Os três sliders estarão "juntos", igual o exemplo que você postou? Por exemplo, se eu mudar o primeiro de 2 para 8 o segundo irá para 30 e o terceiro para 200?

Comment: Acho que eles utilizam esse componente nos sliders https://refreshless.com/nouislider/

Comment: @Randrade exato!

Comment: @GeiltonXavier eu pesquisei este noUiSlider, mas não consegui utiliza-lo também. Por isso, apelei para o jQuery UI Slider, que por ser mais popular, fosse mais tranquilo de encontrar ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primei passo é setar o valor do intervalo dos sliders. Para isso utilizaremos [o exemplo do próprio Jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#steps).

Basta setar o `max` do slider como o tamanho do `array` - 1, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
var arrayCPU = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32];

$("#sliderCPU").slider({
  value: 0, 
  min: 0,
  max: arrayCPU.length - 1
});
```

O próximo passo é utilizar o evento [.slide()](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide) para obtermos o momento em que o o slider for alterado, conforme no exemplo abaixo:

```
$("#sliderCPU").slider({
  value: 0, //valor padrão
  min: 0,
  max: arrayCPU.length - 1,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui)
  }
});
```

Agora, o passo final é interligar todos os sliders. Para fazer isso eu criei uma função chamada `atualizaSliders()` para atualizar todos os sliders.

Para atualizarmos os valores, basta utilizar o método [value](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value) com a posição do `array` que será alterado.

Depois disso tudo, basta juntarmos tudo junto, conforme o código abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //This should have each valid amount that can be selected in the slider 
  var arrayCPU = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32];
  var arrayRAM = [7, 15, 30, 60, 120];
  var arrayDisco = [50, 100, 200, 400, 400];

  $("#sliderCPU").slider({
    value: 0, //valor padrão
    min: 0,
    max: arrayCPU.length - 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      atualizaSliders(ui.value);
    }
  });

  $("#sliderRAM").slider({
    value: 0, //valor padrão
    min: 0,
    max: arrayRAM.length - 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      atualizaSliders(ui.value);
    }
  });

  $("#sliderDisco").slider({
    value: 0, //valor padrão
    min: 0,
    max: arrayDisco.length - 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      atualizaSliders(ui.value);
    }
  });


  function atualizaSliders(index) {
    $("#sliderDisco").slider("value", index);
    $("#disco").html('DISCO: ' + arrayDisco[index])
    $("#sliderRAM").slider("value", index);
    $("#ram").html('RAM: ' + arrayRAM[index])
    $("#sliderCPU").slider("value", index);
    $("#cpu").html('CPU: ' + arrayCPU[index])
  }

})
```

```css
div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<p id="cpu">CPU: 2</p>
<div id="sliderCPU"></div>

<p id="ram">RAM: 7</p>
<div id="sliderRAM"></div>

<p id="disco">DISCO: 50</p>
<div id="sliderDisco"></div>
```

[Veja o exemplo no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/trxv5pvf/2/)

Comment: Perfeito, @Randrade! Espetacular a didática. Muito obrigado.

Comment: tive um problema ao utilizar seu Fiddle... Faça desta maneira: Arraste 1 do CPU (Para o 8) e logo após, mova o segundo slider para 30. Verá que as duas barras de baixo ficam juntas, mas a primeira trava. Pode me ajudar? aparentemente o código está certo... já que a mesma rotina é a mesma para os 3 sliders...

Comment: @MaykelEsser Não consegui reproduzir aqui. Quando você coloca o primeiro no 8 a segunda já estará no 30.

Comment: Qual navegador está utilizando?

Comment: Chrome mesmo... No próprio Fiddle vc consegue simular o problema. Se você rolar o primeiro slider de 2 pra 8, OK... todos movem. Logo após isso, mova o segundo slider (para direita ou para esquerda, tanto faz)... verá que o slider 01 não acompanhará mais.

Comment: Colocando no Debugger do Chrome, recebi este erro: Uncaught Error: no such method 'value ' for slider widget instance

Comment: Será que o index-1 não está causando esse problema, @Randrade?

Comment: Descobri o problema... tinha um espaço no value que dava o problema. A recompensa é sua :)